# Getting Jquery-UI slider value while clicking on slider-track?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I tried to get the value of jquery-ui slider on click of slider track. But I couldn't able to get the value of slider. I'm able to get the value on slide but I couldn't able to get it on click.

```
  <div id="slider"></div>

  var handlers = [25, 50, 75];

  $('#slider').on('click',function(e) {
    //code to get the value
  });

  /*While sliding I'm getting the value*/
   $("#slider").slider({
        min:0,
        max:100,
        steps:20,
        values: handlers,
        slide: function (evt, ui) {
         console.log(ui.values);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. [jQuery UI Slider](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) adds a number of elements and you'll have to be less ambiguous. If you look at the rendered `DIV` that is `#slider`, you will see it has a height of `0` basically. So when the User clicks the handle or the bar, the click event may not bubble up to the `#slider` element.

Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  function log(str) {
    $("#log").prepend("<p>" + str + "</p>");
  }
  var handlers = [25, 50, 75];

  /*While sliding I'm getting the value*/
  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    steps: 20,
    values: handlers,
    slide: function(evt, ui) {
      log("Slide: " + ui.values.join(","));
      $(".ui-slider-handle", this).each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).html(ui.values[i]);
      });
    }
  }).on("click", ".ui-slider-handle", function(e) {
    log("Click: " + $(e.target).parent().slider("values").join(","));
  });
});
```

```css
#log {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7em;
  font-size: 65%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div id="slider" class="ui-helper-clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="log" class="ui-widget"></div>
```

In the Log you can see both `Click` and `Slide` activity. You may consider using `mousedown` or `mouseup` events if you want to be more specific about when the callback should be triggered.

Comment: When the user tried to click the slider track slider handle should not be a moveable one but I need to know the value of the clicked are on the track without moving the handle

Comment: @RajendraPrasad if the handle should not move, then Slider may not be the best widget to use. If you want the value of each slider handle to appear in the handle, that would be a different function. Please clarify.

Comment: Is there any option to achieve that functionality using this slider widget?